# CSS not applied to newly added row on table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table on which the user can select a row. I've made some `CSS` to highlight the selected row. The user can add rows to the original table. The probelm is that the added rows are not highlighted when selected.

**HTML PART :**

```
<table class="table_to_fill" id="table_id">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> title 1 </th>
                    <th> title 2 </th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                   <td>old row 1</td>
                   <td>old row 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                   <td>old row 2</td>
                   <td>old row 1</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS :**

```
.table_to_fill tr:hover, .table_to_fill tr.selected {
background-color: #1E90FF;
color : #fff;
font-weight : bold;}
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(".table_to_fill tr").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});

//to add rows
$("#add_row_button").click(function(){
$('#table_id tr:last').after('<tr><td>new row</td><td>new row</td></tr>');
});
```

So what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**delegated event**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the rows are added to **DOM** after **DOM** ready so event will not fire on newly added rows:

```
$(".table_to_fill").on('click','tr',function(){
$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/FCL88/)

You can understand the jquery Event Delegation from [**here**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @blackbishop: The fundamental issue was that you were binding to the `click` event on *specific elements*. So the new elements that were added didn't have the event bound. Ehsan's solution using event delegation binds the `click` on the **table** instead.

Comment: Agreed with @T.J.Crowder.. OP was binding to tr and it was binded to the ones that were available at DOM ready